# Handling http 302 redirect responses

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, xmlhttprequest

I know that `http 302` responses are handled directly by the browser, and because of that you cannot acces any of the request properties from your source code. But I am wondering if there is any way of intercepting the 302 redirect response. Let me explain myself:

1. My Frontend (Angular) makes an http request to A (I intercept the outgoing request)
2. A responds with `302 Location: B`
3. My Frontend intercepts the `302` response with empty fields, and goes to B
4. **Here I'd like to intercept the response coming from B**

This is my Angular http interceptor code:

```
@Injectable()
export class CasInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('->Interceptor');
    console.log(req);
    return next.handle(req).map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        const response = event as HttpResponseBase;
        console.log('<-Interceptor');
        console.log(response);
        return event;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Browsers do support this but you'll have to check for it and there's no way to polyfill. You'll have to dig deeper in `HttpInterceptor` or write something from scratch. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/redirect

Comment: Isn't the eventual response from B just what you receive as the eventual response to the original http request?

Comment: Not necessarily, that's why I'd like to intercept it: if the user is authenticated the result is the expected from the original request, if not it is a login form. I'd like to be able to check whether the login form came (well, just check if the content type is html) and manually redirect the browser without having to add that logic everywhere, just in the interceptor

Comment: any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

You should get full header from http response.

{observe:"response"} is the magic parameter of angular http client.
So try this one

```js
this.http
.get<any>(requestURL,{observe:"response"})
.subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data.header); //you will see full header here
    console.log(data.url); // you can see redirect url from backend and handle it whatever you want
  },
  err => {
     console.log(err)
  }
```